# Better way then sorting dictionary and getting keys only

Tags: c#, sorting, dictionary

I have a dictionary of customers and associated data (e.g. MoneySpent) and would like to return the sorted list of customers only.
The only solution I figured out so far is this:

```
CustomerData<Customer, int>  //the value here is the money spent
List<KeyValuePair<Customer, int>> sortedListByValue = CustomerData.OrderByDescending(s => s.Value).ToList();
```

Then just going throug the list and obtaining keys. However, I am sure there is an easier way of doing and would be glad for advice.

Comment: What is `CustomerData`? Can you please show that in your code.

Comment: An alternate solution to the accepted answer (well, the same really, but with other syntax), is with query syntax: `var sorted = (from kv in CustomerData orderby kv.Value descending select kv.Value).ToList();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select the `Key` which will give you the customers.

```
var sortedListByValue = CustomerData.OrderByDescending(s => s.Value)
    .Select(x => x.Key).ToList();
```